# Z-Index not being applied

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to get a slider that drops down from the top of my page to go over my menu but can't.

I have applied a position: relative to both of them and tried to put the z-index of the menu to 0 or -10 and I have but the slider to z-index: 10000 with it also postion: relative but it's still going behind the menu.

The page is at http://www.tassolarpanels.com.au/ and the slider in question is the blue "Get a Quick Quote" button on the top right of the screen. As you will see when you press it - it goes behind my menu.

If anyone has any ideas what I am doing wrong I would much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the parent element, in this case, `#sliding-panel-container`, has the correct z-index applied which it currently doesn't -- it is listed as `z-index: 1` which is why it's showing behind the navigation listed as `z-index: 2`.

Try this:

```
#sliding-panel-container {
    ... /* Whatever your other CSS is here */
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `.site` class:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sliding-panel-container {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: That does solve the problem I had regarding the sliding-panel-container I didn't have the z-index on the parent. I presume it's not possible to have the container go above the menu but the .toggle (the button) go behind the menu as it's parent is set to go behind?